# Do nested functions reduce performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nested-function

I have a class `UglyLobster` in a sidescroller-type game that uses artificial intelligence in AS3. `UglyLobster` is a largely self-operating class that determines what it will do next based on the environment. As I am building this artificial intelligence, I find the easiest solution is to use nested functions.

However, I am uncertain if nested functions will affect the performance and cause drag. This `UglyLobster` is not limited to one instance; many will be running at the same time. I've added code to show what I'm trying to do.

```
public class UglyLobster extends Mob {

    //these vars determine what the UglyLobster will do next
    public var behavior = "aggro"
    private var behaviorStep:int = 1

    public function UglyLobster() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,performBehavior)
    }

    public function performBehavior(e) {
        if (behavior == "aggro") {
            aggro()
        }
        if (behavior == "tranq") {
            tranq()
        }
    }

    private function aggro() {
        //it is necessary to have multiple steps.
        //in step 1, the Lobster could bare its lobster fangs,
        //then in step 2, crawl toward a point
        //and in step 3, pinch somebody
        if (behaviorStep == 1) {
            step1()
        }
        if (behaviorStep == 2) {
            step2()
        }
        if (behaviorStep == 3) {
            step3()
        }
        function step1() {
            if (someCondition) {
                behaviorStep = 2
            } else {
                //do whatever happens in step1
            }
        }
        function step2() {
            if (someOtherCondition) {
                behaviorStep = 3
            } else {
                //do whatever happens in step2
            }
        }
        function step3() {
            if (anotherCondition) {
                behaviorStep = 1
            } else {
                behavior = "tranq"
            }
        }
    }

    private function tranq() {
        //do nothing
    }

}
```

Are the nested functions a memory-efficient way to complete the task? If not, how would you set up an artificial intelligence for `UglyLobster`? Examples would really help

Comment: Nested functions are typically considered a poor practice, generally systemic of some greater encapsulation design pattern issue.   Most detrimental to memory is assuring event listeners attached to nested functions are properly disposed.

Comment: nested functions don't achieve anything in term of performance or anything else. They are poor practice because they are a piece of code that cannot be reused in code since their scope is local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Even if i don't like this kind of design and probably, as Jason suggested, there is an architectural design problem, i think there is no need for nested functions.

```
private function aggro() {
    //it is necessary to have multiple steps.
    //in step 1, the Lobster could bare its lobster fangs,
    //then in step 2, crawl toward a point
    //and in step 3, pinch somebody
    if (behaviorStep == 1) {
        step1()
    }
    if (behaviorStep == 2) {
        step2()
    }
    if (behaviorStep == 3) {
        step3()
    }
}

private function step1() {
    if (someCondition) {
         behaviorStep = 2
    } else {
         //do whatever happens in step1
    }
}

private function step2() {
        if (someOtherCondition) {
            behaviorStep = 3
        } else {
            //do whatever happens in step2
        }
 }

private function step3() {
        if (anotherCondition) {
            behaviorStep = 1
        } else {
            behavior = "tranq"
        }
}
```

Comment: the idea is that each different behavior would have its own set of steps. `aggro` would have step1 through step3, and `tranq` would have its own step1 through step3. using nested functions (according to my understanding) would allow the repeated use of these names without having to clutter up the class with unimportant functions. sorry, should have been more clear. however, i agree that this is a poor structure, and i am looking for a reasonable alternative

Comment: If you want to write good AI take a look to FSM (finite state machine) and if you want something more advanced search behaviour tree (this is the state of the art in AI)

Comment: thanks for the lead, especially about the fsm. it was very helpful, and i've found some articles that have pointed me in the right direction. i want to mark this as my accepted answer, but the original question remains unanswered, and i feel i should mark the answer that is most relevant to other people